DDEV mkcert -install fails or hangs when JAVA_HOME misconfigured
I'm trying to setup my local env using ddev and I'm having trouble with keytool.
I've been googling around (And also asked ChatGPT) but I can't find the solution.
The problem I have is that when I use ddev start I get an error related to keytool -list.
When I try the command keytool -list outside of ddev I get asked for the keystore password... I was hoping to configure this information in some file inside .ddev but I can't figure it out.
Thanks!

Please edit to give a link to keytool and saying what it is you want to accomplish. If you have error messages, please show them.

Thanks @rfay . I finally figured it out, the problem was an incorrect definition of JAVA_HOME

Please answer your own question then @Muc, somebody in the future will want to know. Explain exactly what to do to use DDEV with Keytool.

It looks like the mkcert problem here is described in https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/issues/472, and does have to do with JAVA_HOME.

I had a similar (maybe the same) problem today.
As mentioned in other comments the problem is related to the JAVA_HOME environment variable and is not caused by DDEV, but simply by the users environment.
In my case i had
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")

in my .profile, but apparently no longer had javac installed, which caused JAVA_HOME to be set to /usr.
Replacing that with
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:/bin/java::")

solved the problem.
Any other way to set the corrent JAVA_HOME will work as well.
Unsetting JAVA_HOME (setting to an empty value, export JAVA_HOME=) works too.
The problem also does not only happen on ddev start, but can be seen during the setup step mkcert -install as well (mkcert is installed by ddev in my case, Ubuntu 24.04).
I was able to easily reproduce the problem:
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr
$ mkcert -install
The local CA is already installed in the system trust store! 
The local CA is already installed in the Firefox and/or Chrome/Chromium trust store! 
ERROR: failed to execute "keytool -list": exit status 1

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: 

$ export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:/bin/java::")
$ mkcert -install
The local CA is already installed in the system trust store! 
The local CA is already installed in the Firefox and/or Chrome/Chromium trust store! 
The local CA is already installed in Java's trust store! 

